# My custom control needs a custom message pump to handle input events before Windows can. How can I change things so I can use the standard pump?

Tags: c, winapi

One of the window classes in my cross-platform library is a generic drawing area, accessible through an interface like

```
struct AreaHandler {
    void (*Draw)(AreaHandler *, Area *, DrawParams *);
    void (*MouseEvent)(AreaHandler *, Area *, MouseEventParams *);
    BOOL (*KeyEvent)(AreaHandler *, Area *, KeyEventParams *);
};
```

If the `KeyEvent()` method returns `TRUE`, the key is considered "handled" and not passed to the system.

For instance, if the user presses the Tab key and `KeyEvent()` returns `TRUE`, tabbing between controls should be inhibited and the Area will eat the tab key. But if `KeyEvent()` returns `FALSE`, the Tab key should be given to the system, and the system will tab to the next control. Same for `F10`: if `KeyEvent()` returns `TRUE`, the system won't see the `F10` and won't activate the menubar.

My current design works like this:

1. In the message pump, verify that the current focused window is an Area
2. If it isn't, `IsDialogMessage()`, `TranslateMessage()`, and `DispatchMessage()`.
3. If it is, and the message is not a keyboard message, `IsDialogMessage()` and `DispatchMessage()`.
4. Send a special message to the Area to handle the keyboard event, returning whether or not it was handled.
5. If it was handled, discard the original message.
6. Otherwise, `IsDialogMessage()` and `DispatchMessage()`. The Area window procedure will then simply send the messages to `DefWindowProc()`.

This design works, and handles all cases cleanly, but it means I can't use the Area control in anything that doesn't use my standard message pump. In this case, I refer to dialog boxes.

For the common dialogs, I have to disable every top-level window myself to make sure no messages on my Area can come in. This is both inelegant and doesn't let the dialog manager handle the owner window properly.

For custom dialogs, this means if I want modality, I have to implement modality myself, again disabling every window manually and not allowing an owner/owned relationship.

This is unattractive. I could get rid of a lot of code and be able to do things "the right way" by being able to use the standard dialog modal message pump. But I'm not sure how to do that while keeping the input behavior I want (handle messages as they are retrieved from the pump, choosing whether to send them to `IsDialogMessage()`, `TranslateMessage()`, and `DefWindowProc()` as needed).

I know about `WM_GETDLGCODE`. That won't work in two ways. If I process the message in `WM_GETDLGCODE` and handle the event there, I'm going to get an extra window message later I won't know what to do with. Unless there is a way to know tha the message was the one I got before? If I ask for all messages and then process the messages, it'll be too late to give the message back to `WM_GETDLGCODE`. This means that if the Tab key is pressed, I won't be able to do tab navigation anymore, even if the key event wasn't handled.

And then what about `WM_CHAR` messages? The standard dialog message pump likeliy has a `TranslateMessage()` in it, so I'm bound to get those. Is there a reliable way that I can map a `WM_CHAR` to its source `WM_KEYDOWN`, assuming the relationship is 1:1? That way I can either discard the message or pass it to `DefWindowProc()` like I did earlier. But this 1:1 relationship doesn't sound right to me; what about IME?

Would message filters be a solution? I read [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/28/412574.aspx) but I'm not sure if the valid use of a message filter stated here is the same as mine.

This is not MFC; I do not have `PreTranslateMessage()`.

Thanks.

Comment: Read a tutorial, then implement and finally ask for _specific_ problems that arise with a [mcve]?

Comment: I have read tutorials. The function I pasted above is from [my actual implementation](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/master/uitask_windows.c). I'm not happy with it, but I'm not sure how to make it better and less hack-y (surely this isn't an opinion issue, is it?). There must be something that I'm missing about the Windows API here. That's why I'm asking this question, which I tried to make as detailed and specific as possible, complete with what I was thinking of and why it's problematic. I'm not sure how an MCVE would help in this case; this is not a debugging issue.

Comment: "but I'm not sure how to make it better and less hack-y" If that function actually works, it is more of a code-review and off-topic for SO. Anyway, you should not combine multiple questions. Ask about one problem per questions and make sure it is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Have a look at [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @arx that might help with the `IsDialogMessage()` half; the only problem is that I want to give the message *back* to `IsDialogMessage()` once the `WM_KEYDOWN` has arrived and I called `KeyEvent()`. If I simply return `WANTALLKEYS`, I'll get the `WM_KEYDOWN`, but it'll be too late for `IsDialogMessage()`. If I handle it in `WM_GETDLGCODE`, I'd need to be able to ignore the upcoming `WM_KEYDOWN`. And besides, does this come for every `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP`/`WM_SYSKEYDOWN`/`WM_SYSKEYUP`?

Comment: There's nothing "crazy" about implementing your own message loop to handle special cases. That's all `IsDialogMessage` is, wrapped into an API function call. If you have a system that works I don't see any advantage to be gained in changing it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter what I'm calling crazy is what I did/am doing in the question I linked: having to disable all my windows when a dialog box is opened in the first place; it would be better if I specify a specific owner and let the dialog manager handle things, no? Of course, you do have a point; the current system does work as is...

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood but if you want your dialogs to be non-modal simply make them non-modal. Regarding `WM_GETDLGCODE`, the most flexible approach is to inspect the `MSG` you are passed in `lParam` and if you want to handle it simply return `DLGC_WANTMESSAGE`.

Comment: Yeah, there's a misunderstanding. I want to be able to use this control in modal dialogs, and with what I have now the only option is faking modality. I want to know if there's a better way. ...On second thought, maybe that would make for a more logical question to ask in the original question...

Comment: I don't understand why you are concerned about handling `WM_CHAR` messages. Since you're not calling [TranslateMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955.aspx), there aren't any to handle.

Comment: I'm not calling TranslateMessage() above, but the standard dialog loop does. I will definitely rewrite this question, it seems. Sorry for the noise in the meantime.

Comment: Rewrote the question.